# How can I instruct Scrapy to not serialize an item field?

Tags: python, scrapy

As a learning experiment for familiarizing with Scrapy I'm writing a Scraper which checks all the links of a HTML page and reports the status codes of HTTP [HEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) requests directed to them. Fact is, in one of my item definitions I have one item field, namely `parent_url`, treated as metadata - that is, I do not mean to display it in my Scraper's output.

`parent_url` is defined in the `LinkItem` class, as shown below:

```
class LinkItem(Item):
    name = Field()
    url = Field()
    parent_url = Field()   # Identifies what URL this item was extracted from
    status_code = Field()
```

In order to omit `parent_url` from my Spider's output I've tried:

1. Defining `parent_url` in `__init__` as an instance attribute - I got exceptions raised when trying to access it;
2. Assigning to `self["parent_url"]` inside `__init__`, but as already noted by the documentation Scrapy doesn't let assigning to undeclared fields;
3. Assigning `Field(serializer=None)` or `Field(serializer=empty_function)` to `parent_url`, which generated continuous exceptions while scraping and a JSON output with only commas.

Not having yet come to a solution, I'm looking for external help. The `parent_url` field/attribute is used internally within a pipeline, and I don't know what else to substitute it with.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify fields, which should be exported via [FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-fields) setting. For example:

```
# in `settings.py`
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = ['name', 'url', 'status_code']
```

Answer (score 0):

`BaseItemExporter`, the base abstract class of all built-in exporters, provides a [fields_to_export](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.BaseItemExporter.fields_to_export) attribute with the list of the field names to export. This is right-out-of the doc and I'm surprised I haven't noticed it before.