# Scrapy - Drop item field in pipeline ?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I have an `item['html']` field that is needed for `MyExamplePipeline`, but after processing it isn't needed to store into a database with i.e, `MongoDBPipeline`. Is there a way in scrapy to just drop the field `html` and keep the rest of the item? It's needed as part of the item to pass the page `html` from the spider to the pipeline, but I'm not able to figure out how to drop it. I looked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970217/how-can-i-instruct-scrapy-to-not-serialize-an-item-field) SO post that mentioned using [FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-fields) OR [fields_to_export](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.BaseItemExporter.fields_to_export), but the problem is that I don't want to use an item exporter, I just want to feed the item into the next `MongoDBPipeline`. Is there a way to do this in Scrapy? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that. In your `MongoDBPipeline` you need to do something like below

```
del item['html']
```

If that impacts the item in another pipeline then use `copy.deepcopy` and create a copy of item object and then delete `html` before inserting into `mongodb`

Comment: I just had the same idea and `pop()`-ed it out in the pipeline. I think i just got confused searching for an overly `scrapy`-like way to do it, thanks!